# Flex/Flex++ syntax error - "Unrecognized rule"

Tags: bison, lex, flex-lexer, bisonc++

I'm writing a grammar using Flex++ to generate a parser and this block of code always returns an "unrecognized rule" error.

```
%{
#include "Parserbase.h"
%}

%option noyywrap

num         [0-9]+
float       [0-9]+"."[0-9]+
comment     [["//"[.]*\n] | ["/\*"[.]*"\*/"]]
varname     [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*

%%


";"             {return ParserBase::SEMICOLON;}
"\n"            {return ParserBase::ENDLINE;}

"int"           {return ParserBase::INT;}
"="             {return ParserBase::EQUALS;}
{num}           {return ParserBase::NUM;}
{comment}       {return ParserBase::COMMENT;}
{varname}       {return ParserBase::VARNAME;}
```

This always returns the following :

```
bisonc++ Compiler.y
[Warning] Terminal symbol(s) not used in productions:
257: NUM
261: ENDLINE
g++ -c parse.cc
flex++ Compiler.l
Compiler.l:21: unrecognised rule
make: *** [lex.yy.cc] Error 1
```

I've tried moving around the rules, changing the alias to a simple
    [a-zA-Z]
or even just 
    [a-z]
All to no avail, and it's driving me mad... Anyone got any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Can I suggest that you don't have names for single-character special characters: SEMICOLON, EQUALS, etc. Just use ';', '=' etc in the grammar and have your dot rule return `yytext[0].` Saves a lot of mucking around. Strange that you should be returning COMMENT: normally the lexer just eats them up and they don't appear in the grammar at all. Ditto newline, unless your language is line-oriented. Most aren't.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion EJP, I'm basically doing it this way because I'm not entirely sure what's going on and I'm scared of breaking it... pathetic I know, I'll look into it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definition is invalid:

```
comment     [["//"[.]*\n] | ["/\*"[.]*"\*/"]]
```

`[` and `(` are different. `[...]` is a character-class; that is, a list of possible characters which will match a single character. `(...)` is used to group regular expressions.

Also, I don't believe you can insert arbitrary space characters in a Flex++ regex.

So I think that what you intended was:

```
comment     ("//".*\n|"/*".*"*/")
```

Here I've removed the incorrect square brackets, changed the ones which were used for grouping into parentheses, and removed the unnecessary grouping around the alternatives, since `|` has lower precedence than concatenation. I also removed the unnecessary backslash escapes, since quoting is sufficient to make a `*` into a character.

However, that will not correctly match C++ comments:

First, `.*` is greedy (i.e., it will match the longest possible string) so

```
/* A comment */ a = 3; /* Another comment */
```

will be incorrectly recognized as a single comment.

Second, `.` does not match a newline character. So multi-line `/* ... */` comments won't match, because `.*` won't reach to the end of the comment, only to the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the error - not sure why it was referencing a different rule when this one was the problem..? Thanks for the pointers on the regex too!

Comment: @Aunt_Bunny: Afaics, line 21 is the one which uses `{comment}`. But that's based on your copy&paste.

Comment: Hmmm... I could swear it kept on referencing {varname}. I also got an error where I had deleted the 19th line, i.e. 18 lines in the file, then got an "error on line 19" error. Must be a problem with the line numberings. Thanks very much for your help!